# ReactiveCrudRepository is not able to dave data in db

Tags: spring-boot, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

I have two tables in a single database and I want to persist data in tables one after another.

```
    public Mono<Void> createProduct(final Product product){
      AccountProcessingDetails apd = AccountProcessingDetails
            .builder()
            .accountNumber("121212")
            .status("INPROGRESS")
            .build();
      this.productRepository.save(product).map(result-> accountRepository.save(apd));
      return Mono.empty();
    }
```

The following code doesn't save anything in tables and produces no error.

The product object has only been set the following values

```
{
    "description": "iPad",
    "price": 30000.96,
    "prodid": 116
}
```

Script for two tables are as below:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS product(
                    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
                    prodid numeric NOT NULL UNIQUE,
                    description VARCHAR (500),
                    price numeric (10, 2) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ACCOUNT_PROCESSING_DETAILS
(
          ID SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
          ACCOUNT_NUMBER  NUMERIC NOT NULL ,
          STATUS      VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
);
```

Can anyone help me here how to persist data in transactional manner in these two tables?

Comment: Because you are returning `Mono.empty()`, which basically makes all the lines before that useless. Nothing is subscribing to the stream and so nothing will ever get executed.

Comment: Thanks @M.Deinum for the insight... I changed the line to 

this.productRepository.save(product).map(result-> accountRepository.save(apd)).subscribe();

and now it is saving the data in Product table and not on the other one. How to make it work?

Comment: You shouldn't be calling `subscribe` yourself. You should return the stream from the method instead. The second one doesn't save because you don't subscribe to that either. You shouldn't use a `map` but rather a `then` so it becomes part of the stream, now you have basically 2 streams.

Comment: As pointed out `return productRepository.save(product).then();` is the way ro go. `then` will discard the value returned and instead return `void`

Comment: Thanks @Toerktumlare ... Are you saying to use it like, 

return this.productRepository.save(product).then(accountRepository.save(apd)).then(); ?

How do I use transactional feature here? If the second one fails I want to roll back the first one too...

Comment: Im not saying that, im saying how you should solve the problem presented in the question above. How to do transactional is a completely other question. Please google first and try and learn first and if you fail create a new question.